WooCommerce, Gutenberg, ACF Blocks - problem with html characters in duplicated product
I've had a problem for some time and I can't find a solution.
Woocommerce, I have enabled Gutenberg support for products. I have ACF blocks that work and look correctly, but when I try to duplicate a product from each field, either input, textarea or WYSIWYG, where I use HTML characters such as b, strong, span, h2... it changes to the characters as in the attached image:

This happens when trying to duplicate the product either through standard duplication or through other duplication plugins, it is the same. I can't find the answer to this ;/
eg. input field value: <b>test</b> test
duplicated product same field: u003cbu003etestu003c/bu003e test
I have almost tried everything and I cannot find a suitable solution for duplicating products where ACF blocks will correctly duplicate content with html characters.

If anyone has a similar problem, it's an ACF bug, they added it to the roadmap, but no one knows when it will be fixed
